# How to play audio from AVAudioPCMBuffer converted from NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am getting audio PCM 16bit Mono data from udp packets like this:

```
(void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
                                               fromAddress:(NSData *)address
                                         withFilterContext:(id)filterContext
{
...
}
```

I am converting this data into PCM buffer by calling a swift function as below:

```
func toPCMBuffer(data: NSData) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer {
    let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.PCMFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: false)  // given NSData audio format
    var PCMBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity:1024*10)
    PCMBuffer.frameLength = PCMBuffer.frameCapacity

    let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: PCMBuffer.floatChannelData, count: Int(PCMBuffer.format.channelCount))

    data.getBytes(UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(channels[0]) , length: data.length)

    return PCMBuffer
}
```

Data is converted to PCM buffer and i can see its length in logs.
But when i try to play the buffer i hear no voice.
Here is the code for receiving:

```
func toPCMBuffer(data: NSData) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer {
        let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.PCMFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: false)  // given NSData audio format
        var PCMBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity:1024*10)
        PCMBuffer.frameLength = PCMBuffer.frameCapacity

        let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: PCMBuffer.floatChannelData, count: Int(PCMBuffer.format.channelCount))

        data.getBytes(UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(channels[0]) , length: data.length)
        var mainMixer = audioEngine.mainMixerNode
        audioEngine.attachNode(audioFilePlayer)
        audioEngine.connect(audioFilePlayer, to:mainMixer, format: PCMBuffer.format)
        audioEngine.startAndReturnError(nil)

        audioFilePlayer.play()
        audioFilePlayer.scheduleBuffer(PCMBuffer, atTime: nil, options: nil, completionHandler: nil)
        return PCMBuffer
    }
```

Comment: Hi,Have you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: yes i did. i passed the audio in pcm 16 bit from android and played it in IOS device.using audiobufferlist. i will post the answer in a day. sound lags a little.hope u can fix it :)

Comment: Hey, Can you post the solution if it works? Thanks

Comment: okay . i am posting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up using an objective-c function:data is getting converted fine

```
-(AudioBufferList *) getBufferListFromData: (NSData *) data
{
    if (data.length > 0)
    {
        NSUInteger len = [data length];
        //NSData *d2 = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, 1028)];
        //I guess you can use Byte*, void* or Float32*. I am not sure if that makes any difference.
        Byte* byteData = (Byte*) malloc (len);
        memcpy (byteData, [data bytes], len);
        if (byteData)
        {
            AudioBufferList * theDataBuffer =(AudioBufferList*)malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) * 1);
            theDataBuffer->mNumberBuffers = 1;
            theDataBuffer->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize =(UInt32) len;
            theDataBuffer->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
            theDataBuffer->mBuffers[0].mData = byteData;
            // Read the data into an AudioBufferList
            return theDataBuffer;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: How are you scheduling that with your `audioFilePlayer`?

Comment: i used AudioComponentInstance for playing audio through this.